# NameError: name 'player' is not defined - but it was defined, just in another function

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, vlc

The below code gives an error, "NameError: name 'player' is not defined". I dont understand why. When I have the music just playing, without needing to be triggered by the Play button; then the Pause button works. But the moment when I put the command to start playing music within a function, the pause button stops working, and gives the error: "NameError: name 'player' is not defined"

```
import vlc  
import time
import pafy
from tkinter import *

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yV25KhUH1BE"                                                                                   
win = Tk()
pause = 0
def func():
    global pause
    pause = -(pause-1)
    player.set_pause(pause)

def func2():
    video = pafy.new(url)                                                                                                                       
    best = video.getbestaudio()                                                                                                                 
    playurl = best.url 

    instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = instance.media_player_new()                                                                                                         
    media=instance.media_new(playurl)
    media.get_mrl()
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()

btn = Button(win,
                    text = "Pause",
                    command =  func)
btn.pack()
btn2 = Button(win,
                    text = "play",
                    command =  func2)
btn2.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

The code above is just a trial, not the full project.

Comment: ```player``` is defined in a different code block, therefore you can't access it,
another note: ```global ...``` is a bad practice, I suggest to pass whatever variables you need as function arguments

Comment: Thank you! 
Passing the variables seems to work, I just intuitively didnt think that even with a music player, it can just be passed as a variable. But it seems unproblematic.
Thanks for the tip about the Globals, gonna change that.

Comment: little question though: can i return vars to a button (ie when the function was called from a button)?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, what do you mean by "return vars to a button"?

Comment: You say, global variables are not good.
So my question is: If a certain function is called by  a button, and the button passes on a variable (lets call it "counter", and its value is 0), and then the function does something to the variable (Counter = 1 for example), and then the function hast return(counter) at the end. 
CAn the button then somehow store that returned variable (counter, which is now 1) somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation,
If I understood correctly, just store the value that the function returns like so:
```v = func(button)```

Comment: For your case, you can create `instance` and `player` in the global space instead of inside `func2()`.

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I understand, the error is coming from

```
def func():
    global pause
    pause = -(pause-1)
    player.set_pause(pause)
```

This might be because "player" isn't actually defined.

In func2, you have defined  `player = instance.media_player_new()` so it's doesn't throw any error.
In "func", you missed it.

I think that is causing an issue. Try defining "player" globally. That might help.